# Image in html of TextView not being displayed properly

Tags: android

I have a TextView which I place into an AlertDialog like this:

```
final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.alert_quickhints_html)));     
alert.setView(textView);
```

My alert_quickhints_html is:

```
  <string name="alert_quickhints_html"><![CDATA[<p><b>Time correction</b><br/>Some text</p>                                     
  <p><img src = "file:///android_asset/icon.png"><b>Report summary</b><br/>Bla bla</p>.../>
```

I have icon.png in my assests folder. When I execute this code I can see a little red square at the place where the icon should appear. Somehow it seems the icon is not rendered correctly. It's a PNG with transparency. Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android `TextView` supports only limited set of HTML tags and `<img>` is definitely not one of them. If you really need to show complex html within a dialog, use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

**UPD**
Actually I was wrong, `<img>` is kinda supported. Use [Html.fromHtml(String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29) method (note imageGetter parameter), to supply images for your html.