# Image is not displaying in textview using Html.fromhtml

Tags: android, image, textview

I have the HTML string as follows

```
String htmlstr=" This is my image <img src='/sdcard/pic1.jpg' /> and the my second image is <img src='/sdcard/pic2.jpg' />"
```

I am using

```
txtimg.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlstr));
```

But the problem is it displays 1 default small squre with green color instead of image

Please help me to display a image

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out this link




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161280/image-in-html-of-textview-not-being-displayed-properly

Comment: @GinerJim: Thanks for your comment.But i want to display images from sdcard and I have tried imageGetter but it dose not work for me do you have any idea how to use imageGetter  in my case

Comment: @Hemantxp : it don't working in your case mean?

Comment: @Hemantxp I posted solution for your problem. That works well for me.

Comment: I got a solution for it and i posted my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.jpg";

ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return d;
    }
};

Spanned htmlstr= Html.fromHtml("<img src='" + path + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
TextView out_unit1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtViewCm2);
out_unit1.setText(htmlstr);
```

It works well for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer But i modified some logic for ImageGetter and it is working for me
I will put my code as answer

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me as follows

```
txtimg.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlstr, new ImageGetter() {                 
                @Override
                public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                    String path =  source;

                    Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
                    bmp.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmp.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    return bmp;
                }
            }, null));
```